# Python Regression giving 2 different results

Tags: python, linear-regression, seaborn

So I have the data below:

```
1995    0.379769  
1996    0.384967  
1997    0.344343  
1998    0.384179  
1999    0.282823  
2000    0.337774  
2001    0.298339  
2002    0.351266  
2003    0.338709  
2004    0.390772  
2005    0.410985  
2006    0.378565  
2007    0.383554  
2008    0.387875  
2009    0.471277  
2010    0.407915  
2011    0.400196  
2012    0.458957  
2013    0.478453  
2014    0.564311
2015    0.459423
```

and when I run the statsmodel OLS regression

```
lm = smf.ols(formula='Values ~ Year', data=v).fit()
print lm.summary()
```

I get an intercept of -15.0747 and a coefficient of 0.0077.  However this looked off to me especially when I graphed it against the data.

[image]

As you can see when I graph the line of best fit against the data/seaborn regression line I get a line that is seemingly parallel but visually below where it needs to be,

I use this to produce that graph

```
ax = sns.regplot(x = "X", y = "y", data = test)
ax.plot([0, 2016], [-15.0747, 0.4485], c='r')
ax.set_xlim(1990,2016)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
```

Can someone tell me where this error is occurring and why it is happening?

EDIT

So I noticed I gave the wrong subset of the data to Excel, but that still doesn't change the fact that when I plot the regression line from SMF it is different than from seaborn

Comment: Excel is correct. Could you please provide a complete, runnable Python script that includes all the data in the code and that demonstrates the issue? (It could be, for example, that your Python dataframe isn't what you think it is.)

Comment: We would need to know exactly how both the statsmodel function works (which we could inspect the source code to find out), and we would need to know exactly how the excel regression function works (which we will not ever know). Maybe excel's regression does not use an OLS approach?

Comment: This is the result I get from statsmodels: `const        -15.4762`, `x1             0.0079`

Comment: I've edited my original question

Comment: Sorry it was a rounding error, this can be close, I feel like an idiot.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @qwertylpc just go ahead and answer your own question instead of closing it in case someone else needs it one day